# Visual Studio Docker HTTPS setup fails

Tags: macos, visual-studio, docker

I am trying to get a project running with the new visual studio 2019 on mac.

However, I am getting the following error.

```
Application startup exception: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = KestrelServer (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.Internal.ITransportFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)' on type 'KestrelServer'. ---> error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.Internal.ITransportFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)' on type 'KestrelServer'. ---> error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file (See inner exception for details.) ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
   at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, String fileName, String password)
   at Identity.API.Program.<>c.<BuildWebHost>b__1_3(ListenOptions listenOptions) in /Users/pp/www/amritaDEV/appraisals/Amrita/src/Services/Identity/Identity/Program.cs:line 56
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions.Listen(IPEndPoint endPoint, Action`1 configure)
   at Identity.API.Program.<>c.<BuildWebHost>b__1_0(KestrelServerOptions options) in /Users/pp/www/amritaDEV/appraisals/Amrita/src/Services/Identity/Identity/Program.cs:line 54
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.CreateServiceContext(IOptions`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
      Application startup exception
```

I have been doing: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6199

and i completed the steps but got the following error. Something with the certificates, names or places maybe?

I am on Visual Studio 8. Visual Studio 7 didn't have HTTPS problem for localhost

Comment: Were you able to figure what was going wrong?

Comment: Any update on this?